# Can we use one hot encoding instead of for loops?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, anomaly-detection

I have an anomaly detection model, that I run per store with a bunch of features. 
I intend to run this code, everyday, per store. Now, lets say I have 8000 stores, I would imagine, I should write a for loop and iterate and create the model per store:

`final` is the dataframe that consists of all the stores

Something like:

```
for store in final['StoreNbr'].unique():
   run the model.
```

My input features include: Store number, Cashier, etcc (many other features). Can I use one hot encoding for the StoreNbr column and then run the model once as opposed to a for loop and running the model per storenbr?

Comment: So if I understand well you want to run a new model every day, one model per store? And use each day the past training data plus the new data of the day ?

Comment: Yes I want to run a new model every day per store. For a day's run. I dont need the old day data. So, If I run something today - run per day per store and get the results to the user. Second day - pick up data for second day - run per store the model for that day and get the users the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to train the data each day and have a new model per store and per day, **you should not use** One Hot Encoding. If you do One Hot Encoding you will get one single trained model which will learn from the data you have in all the stores. I suppose you do not want one trained model but one model for each store.